# java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, pdf

"I am getting 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response' exception.
"

I want to print certificates of all user's those who belong to classxxx.
Suppose classxxx has 4 users so all 4 user's certificates should print one by one.

But my code printing first user's certificate only.

Here is my code.

```
String type = "certification";
List<LBUser> classRoster = null;
classRoster = LBUser.getClassRoster(classId,true,false,false);
//Here i get list of users

if(classRoster != null && classRoster.size() > 0) {
for(LBUser user : classRoster) {

if ("certification".equals(type)){%>
<%@ include file="certificate_certification.jsp" %>
<%} %>
<%

ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

try { 
Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER.rotate());
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, buffer);
writer.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.VERSION_1_6); 

document.open();
PdfContentByte over = writer.getDirectContent();
PdfContentByte under = writer.getDirectContentUnder();

//Some image related and Pdf related code

document.close(); 

DataOutput dataOutput = new DataOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
//response.getOutputStream().... Here am getting same object
byte[] bytes = buffer.toByteArray();
response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
{
    dataOutput.writeByte(bytes[i]);
}

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    try{
        if(buffer != null){
            buffer.close();
            buffer = null;
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        buffer = null;
    }       
}
} // classRoster forloop closed
```

"This error already present on google and i follow all the step but but none of that worked."

Thanks.

Comment: You can only use either #getOutputStream() or #getWriter() for any single Servlet response.

Comment: If you want to give the user a PDF to download, you shouldn't be writing a JSP in the first place! It's for producing HTML (or maybe other text output). Use a Servlet instead!

Comment: Thanks for response, but i can't use servlet because entire project developed in jsp.

Comment: I debuged and at this line getting same object 'DataOutput dataOutput = new DataOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());'

Comment: @rahim: that's a terrible reason for not using Servlets. Just because you used a hammer for everything, doesn't mean it's the right tool to screw in a screw. But if you insist, then make sure that nothing in your JSP actually produces any output. That includes "harmless" stuff like the newline after your certificate check. Ideally, just start the file with `<%` and end it with `%>` without any other directives anywhere.